# SSIS - Dynamic Expression from DataBase

Tags: database, dynamic, ssis, expression

I'm working on a `SSIS` where i need to save a file. But this file has its filename stored in database in an expression format like `"TEST" + ".xml"`

When i retrieve the expression filename i can't evaluate it to override my file connection.

Can you help me?

Comment: Use `Expressions` in `File Connection Manager` and specify the value for the property `Connection String` and set `Delay Validation` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

First make the connection manager to a temp flat file. Once created go to the connection manager's properties and choose expression. Write the expression for the connection string changing it to something like `="path\to\file\" + @var`. You may also need to set delay validation to true on the file manager and the data flow task.

there is also a blog post [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11113/ssis-dynamically-set-flat-file-connection-manager.aspx) with more detail, admittedly it is using the flat file as a source but the principle should be the same.